# VideoData is empty

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to find a way to upload video from UIImagePickerController.
The below code, it returns back a 0 length for video data but I'm positive that the video path is correct because it returns back something like

/private/var/mobile/Applications/22318D96-B5B5-4C92-A8EB-869311275E40/tmp//trim.‌​AE6xnl.MOV

```
NSString *videoPath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:videoPath ofType:@"mov"]];
int videoSize = [videoData length];
NSLog(@"Video path: %d", moviePath);
NSLog(@"Video size: %d", videoSize);
```

Any idea what is the correct param to put for **pathForResource**?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
NSURL* movieUrl = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:movieUrl];
if(videoData)
{
   int videoSize = [videoData length];
  NSLog(@"Video path: %d", movieUrl);
  NSLog(@"Video size: %d", videoSize);
}
```